# Query to Get Data Dependent On Another Column, But Only If It Appears Once

Tags: mysql, select

I've got a MySQL table like the following:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|  ID  |  State   |  Name   |     City       |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  PA1 |  PA      |  Foo    |    Philly      |
|  VA1 |  PA      |  Foo    |    Philly      |
|  DC1 |  VA      |  Foobar |  Washington    |
|  ME2 |  ME      |  Barfoo |   Portland     |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I want to do a SELECT statement where I SELECT only those rows where `State = SUBSTR(ID, 1, 2)`, *unless* the `Name` only appears in the table one time. In other words, I want to end up with the following table:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|  ID  |  State   |  Name   |     City       |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  PA1 |  PA      |  Foo    |    Philly      |
|  DC1 |  VA      |  Foobar |  Washington    |
|  ME2 |  ME      |  Barfoo |   Portland     |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

In the second row, the State does not equal the substring of ID and that 'Name' ("Foo", in this example) appears in the table more than once, so we don't get that row. However, I also want the third row, even though State again does not equal the substring of ID, because that 'Name' only appears once in the original table.

Any ideas as to what query I could use to achieve this? I've been playing around with it for quite some time without success. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from   myTable
where  State = SUBSTR(ID, 1, 2) or
       Name in (select Name from myTable group by Name having count(*)=1)
```

Comment: depends, OP first stated 'only those rows where State = SUBSTR(ID, 1, 2), unless the Name only appears in the table one time', but then stated 'appears in the table more than once, so we don't get that row'. I wasn't entirely clear what was appropriate, but either way  it can be done using a `HAVING` subquery

Comment: @paul I did mean the `OR`, sorry if the explanation was confusing. Either way, I got it to work, so thanks!

Comment: @paul I updated your answer to use `OR` otherwise this did not work and made no sense being the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following with an `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where state = SUBSTR(ID, 1, 2)
  or exists (select count(Name) CountName, Name
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.name = t2.name
              group by Name
              having count(name) = 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c238/14)

Returns the result:

```
|  ID | STATE |   NAME |       CITY |
-------------------------------------
| PA1 |    PA |    Foo |     Philly |
| DC1 |    VA | Foobar | Washington |
| ME2 |    ME | Barfoo |   Portland |
```

Comment: +1 for the SQL Fiddle, though I took the other answer just because it's working for me well and it came slightly sooner.